# Line plot with mean and sd in R

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

### It as answered

I would like to do a plot if show the heating curve of a ring where the points have the mean and standard deviation. 
There are the data:

```
mean_ring = c(25.81667, 16.29167, 17.99167, 19.25000, 19.90833, 20.81667)    
sd_ring = c(4.806025, 1.803259, 1.864724, 2.436652, 2.344610, 3.300918)    
time = c("Pre", 0, 5, 10, 15, 20)   
df_ring <- data.frame(mean_ring, sd_ring, time)
```

thank you!

Comment: What pray tell is a "heating curve"?

Comment: How would you like to represent this "heating curve"? Perhaps using a line graph, with time on the X-axis and mean_ring on the Y-axis?

If so, these pages might help you:
[line plot](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html),
[error bars](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_linerange.html)

Comment: I also noticed that the first value of `time` is not a numeric. Why is the first value not 0?

Comment: Because this is the acclimate temperature before the cold stress (time 0).

Comment: So you have an object, you cool it down, then you measure the amount of energy it reabsorbed at different time points? If that's the case, does it make sense to include the pre-cold stress temperature in the plot, if all you're interested in is the rise in temperature after the cold stress?

Comment: @MarianeCampos, did my answer below answer your question? If not please feel free to let me know how we can help you.

Comment: I need the pre-cold stress to compare the initial and final temperature.

Answer (score 2):

would something like,

```
timeNumeric <- seq(-5, 20, 5)

# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df_ring, aes(x= timeNumeric, y= mean_ring)) + 
       geom_line() + geom_point() + 
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_ring-sd_ring, ymax= mean_ring + sd_ring), 
         width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.05))
p + labs(title="Heating curve of a ring", y="Mean temperature", x = "Time")  + 
       scale_x_time(breaks = timeNumeric, labels = time)
```

[image: Heating curve of a ring]

Comment: Thank you Eric, it is exactly  what I needed.

Comment: @MarianeCampos, Glad to hear that. Don't forge to close the question by marking it as answered.